# Php echo array items one by one by click (only unique)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

Gooda.
Please help to fix a little bit my php code:
Here is code:

```
<?php
$urls = array("http://www.site1.com",
"http://www.site2.com",
"http://www.site2.com");
$url = $urls[array_rand($urls)];
?>
<?php echo $url ?>
```

I need to echo each array items one by one by clicking link or button.
So it will print website1 then after click button website2.

I use this code for button:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#button").click(function () { 
   $("#frame").attr("src", "<?php echo $url ?>");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing PHP and JavaScript. PHP is run on the server before the page is delivered to the client. JavaScript is run on the client side after the page has been downloaded. It is therefore impossible for JavaScript to call PHP without making  new request to the server.

You must ether store the PHP variable in JavaScript or load it by [Ajax](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14142/AJAX-Explained).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access `PHP` variables with `JavaScript`

You could for example store the array from `PHP` in a `JavaScript` array

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  <?php 
    $urls = array("http://www.site1.com", "http://www.site2.com", "http://www.site2.com");
    echo 'var sites = ["'.$urls[1].'","'.$urls[1].'","'.$urls[1].'"], i= 0;';
    //you will probably have to use for here
  ?>

   $("#button").click(function () {
      if (i > i.length) { i=0 }
      $("#frame").attr("src", sites[i]);
      i++;
   });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$urls = array("http://www.site1.com",
"http://www.site2.com",
"http://www.site2.com");
$url = $urls[array_rand($urls)];
echo '<script>'.'var urls = [];';
foreach($url as $key){
  echo 'urls.push('.$key.');';
}
echo '</script>';
```

then for button:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#button").click(function () { 
   $("#frame").attr("src", urls.pop()");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The other solution is to render the clickable button's with php at the server so when the page has been downloaded the button's are already there in html Code.

You could use something like this:

```
foreach($urls as $url) {
echo '<a href="$url"><input type="button" name="$url" value="$url"></a>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your first script is in ajax/geturl.php
(please note that with the script as it is (with random) you coul get the same url twice.)

then on your page it should be something along the lines
(providing you have JQuery of course)

```
$.get('ajax/geturl.php', function(data) {
   $("#frame").attr("src", data);
});
```